# Walrus operator equivalent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there an equivalent of Python's walrus operator ':=' in JavaScript? I know it's possible to do:

```
for (let i = 0; (result = foo(i)) < N; i++) {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

but I want `result` to be constrained to the scope of the for-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could declare `result` inside of the `for`'s scope.

```
for (let i = 0, result; (result = foo(i)) < N; i++) {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative to [Nina's good approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70414127/157247): Any time you want to have a variable in a narrower scope than its surroundings, you can also use a freestanding block:

```
{
    let result;
    // ...
}
```

That would free you from using `for` without an increment expression (I'm of the school that all three parts of a `for` should be used, or use a different loop):

```
{
    let i = 0, result;
    while ((result = foo(i++)) < N) {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const foo = x => x;
const N = 5;
{
    let i = 0, result;
    while ((result = foo(i++)) < N) {
        // Do stuff...
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```