# Walrus operator TypeScript equivalent if statements

Tags: node.js, typescript

Extremely similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70414113/walrus-operator-equivalent-in-javascript), but w.r.t to if statements:

```
import { argv } from "process"

function foo(input: string): boolean
{
    return input === "ppp";
}

for (let i=0, v; v = foo(process.argv[2]) && i < 1; i++)
//if (let v = foo(process.argv[2]))
{
    console.log(v);
}
// console.log(v); <--- compile-time error, good !
```

Is there any way to define a [Walrus](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics)-like operator inside if statements?

```
% npx tsc --target es2022 --moduleResolution node example.ts
example.ts:9:9 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

9 if (let v = foo(process.argv[2]))
          ~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible with `if`. The IMHO best thing you can do if you want to narrow down the scope of your `v` is to create a new block

```
...
{ 
  let v= ...; 
  if (v) {
    ...
  }
  console.log(v); // no error here
} 
console.log(v) // compile error here
...
```

You can of course sort of abuse the `for` loop, by `break`ing out of it on the first iteration or setting `v` to a falsey. Similar to what you did with the `i`, but without the need of an additional variable.

```
for (let v = ...; !!v;) {
  console.log(v);
  break;
}
```

or

```
for (let v = ...; !!v; v=undefined) {  //or whatever falsey fits the type of your v
  console.log(v);
}
```

But IMHO both variants are quite ugly and not very intuitive. (The second seems slightly better) And if someone accidentially removes the `break` you end up in an endless loop.

I'd go with the additional block ...

And in your presented case, where `v` is actually a `boolean`, you don't need the variable at all. You can just do'

```
if (foo(...)) {
  console.log(true);
}
```

But I doubt you'll have `boolean`s in all of your usecases ...